# Graphics corruption/artifacts on laptop - hardware or software issue?

Tags: graphics, dell, laptop, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 (9300) laptop with Intel graphics and I have occasionally been having issues with graphics corruption/glitches/artifacts.  It's under warranty for a couple more months, but I'm having trouble verifying if this is a software issue or a hardware issue since the problem only pops up once in a while.

Here's some video of it acting up...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOa8f.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJc7R.jpg

When that happened, I first tried a video screen capture, but there was no corruption in the replay.

I tried closing the laptop and coming back to it later... there was no problem immediately when I came back to it.  Same with rebooting.

I tried plugging in an external monitor... there was no problem displayed on the external monitor.

I tried working the laptop lid/hinge back and forth, but this didn't affect anything.

Finally, based on Dell support's suggestion, I tried changing the screen resolution and then clicking "revert" when it asks if I want to keep the new settings.  Oddly enough, this seems to have fixed the issue for the time being, but they don't tell me what they think this indicates.

So... do any of you have any thoughts on whether this is hardware or software or how to determine more definitively which is the case?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you kind of answered it yourself - if it's not showing on external display, than it's extremely unlikely it's a software issue.

You can test one more thing - boot a live distro. You can try Live Ubuntu 20.10 and see if it happens. You can then try something older like Ubuntu 16.04 or some different distro (best if slightly older and not ubuntu based)

If your screen is acting up on those as well, you almost have it 100% it's hardware.

Could be provoked by heating up, or 3D, or some malfunctioned unit (eg maybe video encoder). I have one card that works awesome in 2D, but as soon as it touches 3D it goes bonkers, and stays like that until shutdown and new boot.

Try repeating the steps (encoding video, running 3D games, something heavy and for a longer period, like 10-15min at least to let it heat up).

Then if it shows again, try to do similar on those Live CD distros.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really have a clue as to what is triggering it to act up.  My use is super mundane and regular .  I haven't seen any tie to heat either.  The biggest issue I'm finding with trying to eliminate the software aspect is that it goes away if the monitor goes off and back on, either by closing the lid, timing out, or even changing the resolution and it acts up randomly after an hour or more of use, otherwise I would just reboot into the BIOS when it's having issues and see if they persist.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Dell XPS 9570. Looks like a Mesa 20.2 issue that has been resolved in Git. You can update to Mesa 20.3 either [building from Git](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/3599) or from the [following PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers), running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This has resolved my issue.

Comment: I thought this was a promising suggestion (and obviously it would be good news), and I was able to update my driver using your instructions, but the issue popped back up shortly after.  Thank you anyway, Alex.